# DatePickerDialog on EditText Click Event

Tags: android, datepicker

I have multiple DatePickers in my App and I am trying to single method to set the datepicker for multiple TextView rather than putting a Datepicker to each TextView, Date dialog seems to be appearing correctly but the change gets updated to only the last item.

Here is the method that I created

```
public void Setdate( final EditText setdateEditview){

        setdateEditview.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        setdateEditview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DatePickerDialog.show();
                Log.d ("ttt","herre we o"+setdateEditview);
            }


        });

        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                Log.d ("ttt","herre we o"+setdateEditview);
                setdateEditview.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }

        },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    }
```

I'm calling above method by this....

```
mCustomerDueDateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_CustommerDueDate);
mForecastedDueDateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_ForcastedDueDate);
Setdate(mCustomerDueDateEditText);
Setdate(mForecastedDueDateEditText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the method signature like this, and loop through it when you want to update.

```
   public void Setdate( final EditText... setdateEditviewList){

                setdateEditview.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                setdateEditview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        DatePickerDialog.show();
                        Log.d ("ttt","herre we o"+setdateEditview);
                    }


                });

                Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                DatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                        newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                        Log.d ("ttt","herre we o"+setdateEditview);

               //loop through the EditText here
                 EditText et;
                for(int = 0; i<setdateEditviewList.length; i++){
                          et = setdateEditviewList[i];
                          et.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));

           }
                    }

                },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            }
```

call the method as follows:

```
mCustomerDueDateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_CustommerDueDate);
mForecastedDueDateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_ForcastedDueDate);
Setdate(mCustomerDueDateEditText, mForecastedDueDateEditText);
```

Comment: Thanks, seeing issue from -->>for(EditText et :setdateEditviewList ).... it says "for" cannot be running with 'EditText'  Type...